# Hibernate / Spring: EntityManager.lock would work as expected, em.find not

Tags: spring, postgresql, hibernate, transactions, locking

i am trying to use manual locking inside a spring @Transactional method, using

```
EntityManager.find(class, id, LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE);
```

However, when viewing the sql, hibernate does NOT generate any `select ... for update` statements (acquire an exclusive lock on the DB row) as i would expect, and the method does not synchronize correctly.

Strangely, calling `em.lock()` after fetching the entity using `em.find()` causes a `select ... for update` as I would expect for find(), as does adding an `@Lock(PESSIMISTIC_WRITE)` annotation to a fetching query.
However I would prefer using em.find() over the other two methods, but i cannot get that to work.

So, why is EntityManager.find silently ignoring lock options, while other locking methods work?

I am using Hibernate 5.4.4.FINAL, tried upgrading to 5.4.11.FINAL.
I also tried setting Isolation levels to SERIALIZABLE and READ_COMMITTED in the @Transactional.
Neither of these altered my results.